# Finding an entry in Adj(A), given matrix A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics

I'm doing a practice exam and I came up with a different answer than the key, I'm not sure where I went wrong.

the question: Find the (2,4) entry of the matrix Adj(A),

if A = $$\begin{matrix}1 & 1 & 0 & 2\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & 0\\ 0 & 2 & -2 & 2\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\ \end{matrix}$$

I eliminated row 2 and column 4 then found the determinant of the resulting matrix and ended up with an answer of 2....the key says the answer is 4.

Comment: The adjugate is the *transpose* of the cofactor matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to take the minor $\;(-1)^{2+4}A_{42}\;$ , which is

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}1&0&2\\0&2&0\\0&\!-2&2\end{pmatrix}=4$$